# Creating a File Parser in C++

Tags: c++, parsing, fileparsing

I am trying to create a parser class that will parse a file based on " " and place the words into a linked list.

```
class FileReader
{
public:
   FileReader(char* file)   
   {

    ifstream fout (file, ifstream::in);

    string hold;

    while (fout.good())
    {
        getline (fout, hold, " ");
        cout << hold;

    }

    fout.close();

    }

};
```

The function `getline(fout, hold, " ")` is not recognizing " " as the delimiter.

I have not coded the linked list part as of yet so this is just the parsing part of the program.

Also would there be a better way to create a parser?

Comment: If regex is an option, this might help: http://criticalindirection.com/2016/01/05/lex-based-config-parserreader/

Answer (score 3):

It should just work like this:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <list>
#include <string>

std::ifstream infile(file);

std::list<std::string> words(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(infile),
                             std::istream_iterator<std::string>());
```

Now `words` is your linked list of whitespace-separated tokens.

Lesson: The best kind of code is the one you don't have to write.

Comment: @user814628: You were prepared to use `std::getline`, so... small difference.

Comment: @user814628 No sense in rewriting code when code to do the same task is already written and well-tested.

Comment: It's very easy to overlook some of the nifty features in the standard library ... ;)

Comment: @KerrekSB judging from OP's code, it doesn't seem like he is at level where he would understand what exactly are those lines of code doing. I just posted a simple solution to which I believe he could grasp at this point more easily.However, I did fail to mention better solutions, to which you have provided. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The last parameter in `getline` is a `char` not a `string`. Looking at your current code, you want `getline(fout,hold,' ')` or just `getline(fout,hold)` -- *if you want the whole line.

*****: edit

Comment: `getline(fout, hold)` will get an entire line ... not just individual words.